# Trouble with variables (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a newbie with programming and I'm in trouble with this code:

```
def supercalcx(a, b):
    n = a
    while a <= b:
        n = n * a
        a = a + 1
    print(n)
```

The IDE give me the error: "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'", but I'm sure the inputs are ints or floats, can anyone explain me the problem. Thanks !

Comment: What arguments did you pass to your `supercalcx()` function when you called it? If you don't know in the case that you passed variables, please include more code.

Answer (score 0):

This function works:

```
>>> def supercalcx(a, b):
...     n = a
...     while a <= b:
...         n = n * a
...         a = a + 1
...     print(n)
...
>>> supercalcx(2, 4)
48
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not convert between data types. A very crude method of this is to do the following below:

```
def supercalcx(a,b):
    n = int(a)
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    while a <= b:
        n = n * a
        a = a + 1
    print(n)
```

A couple of suggestions to improve your code:

A function should rarely have the `print()` function inside of it; instead, use the `return` keyword. You can change `a = a + 1` to `a += 1` and `n = n * a` to `n *= a`. You can also introduce `try` and `except` which will *attempt* to perform whatever is tabbed under `try` and if something throws an error specified by the `except` block, it will then perform whatever is tabbed under `except`. A somewhat improved version is below:

```
def supercalcx(a, b):
    try:
        n = int(a)
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
    except ValueError:
        return "Unable to convert to integers!"
    while a <= b:
        n *= a
        a += 1
    return n

print(supercalcx("1", 2))
print(supercalcx(1, 2))
```

Comment: Using `except` without a specific error is bad practice (a majority of the time). Try `except` with `ValueError`.

Comment: Oops, forgot about that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I input a float value, how I can do ?

Comment: You could change all `int` portions of your code to `float` and change `Unable to convert to integers!` to `Unable to convert to floating point!`